# Enabling crayon in the RStudio console

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I enable `crayon`-powered coloring in the RStudio console? For me, all the characters are white, and the encoding characters print out as literal text.

```
install.packages("crayon")

options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)
crayon::make_style("dodgerblue3")

## Crayon style function, dodgerblue3: example output.

options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)
crayon::make_style("dodgerblue3")

## Crayon style function, dodgerblue3: [38;5;32mexample output.[39m
```

Comment: Which version of RStudio are you using? It works fine for me but I run dailies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible when using RStudio v1.1, which is only available as a preview right now (see https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/13/rstudio-v1.1---the-little-things/). So make sure you have an updated preview version of RStudio v1.1 first, then it should work.

Comment: I am using 1.0.153. Looking at the [download page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download), I thought that was the latest version. It did not occur to me to try a pre-release. But I just downloaded it, and it is a breath of fresh air. Solved this issue too.